# add dependency to cuurent kernel version

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, packaging, debian

I want to depend my deb package to current kernel version that is installed on machine.

for example if my kernel version is 3.13.0-77 my deb file depends on linux-headers-3.13.0.77-generic

if I add "linux-headers-$(uname -r)" to Depends field in debian/control file, dpkg-buildpackage returns an error in dpkg-gencontrol process.

how can I add this feature in my packaging?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0.77-generic (>= 3.13.00.77), linux-headers-3.13.0.77-generic (<< 3.13.00.78)
```

$(uname -r) in this case does'nt cut it.

Comment: thanks, but in this way when my kernel changed I must repackaging!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your dependency be `linux-headers-generic` since, if it is installed, the headers for the currently running kernel, no matter what it is, are also installed.

Comment: thanks, but my repository has various version of Linux-headers, and this solution not good for me